# backup laravel mysqldump

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

i try use laravel package to backup database when try backup this error appear use Artisa::call 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. i user windows and add mysql path in windows environment and when run the command in cmd work correctly

```
'mysql' => [
          'driver'            => 'mysql',
          'host'              => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
          'database'          => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
          'username'          => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
          'password'          => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
          'charset'           => 'utf8',
          'collation'         => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
          'prefix'            => '',
          'strict'            => false,
          'engine'            => null,
          'dump' => [
             'dump_command_path' => 'd:\xampp\mysql\bin', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`; this is a working example from MAMP on Mac OS
             'use_single_transaction',
             'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
             // 'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
             // 'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue',
          ]
      ],
```

Comment: in app/config/database.php at every driver you want to backup add:
'dump' => [ 'setDumpBinaryPath' => 'C:\\path to your database\\mysql\\bin' ],could this be the problem?

Comment: hi i solved it works if i launch it from http: // localhost / marco / public / admin / backup
if you run it from http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/backup it gives me
mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP / IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect
what can I do?